# Cloning multiple objects and returning them back in response with DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

My goal is to clone mulitple objects and serialize them so that I can return the result back in my REST Api. Currently my code looks like this:

```
objects_to_clone = MyModel.objects.filter(...)
new_objects = []
for obj in objects_to_clone:
    clone = copy.deepcopy(file)
    clone.id = None
    # Do something else with the cloned object
    new_objects.append(clone)
serializer = MySerializer(data=new_objects, many=True) # YIELDS ERROR
if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

The problem with this code is that Django justfully yields

> nonFieldErrors - Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got MyModel

How is it possible to overcome this without having to find dirty workarounds ?

Comment: the problem might be with copy.deepcopy, try using the Model Class itself instead.
`clone = MyModel(obj)`.

Comment: How are you going to copy the entire object using the class model ? Could you please provide a code snippet ?

Comment: you basically don't even need to call the copy method here. https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/copy.html

all you have to do is `obj.id = None` and when you'll call save on this updated object, it will create a new entry in database which will have a new `PK` but all the remaining values will remain same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are passing the models to the serializer instead of a dictionary.
You can convert the models to a dictionary by using `.values()` and specifying the fields you want returned.

The values() method returns a QuerySet that returns dictionaries, rather than model instances, when used as an iterable.

For example what you currently have evaluates to  something like this

```
MyModel.objects.filter(...)
<QuerySet [<MyModel: Random Title>]>
```

but if you make use of [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values), the result of the same query will be

```
MyModel.objects.filter(...).values()
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Model 1'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Model 2'}]>
```

at the end of the day, your code will be something like this

```
objects_to_clone = MyModel.objects.filter(...).values()
new_objects = []
for obj in objects_to_clone:
    obj.id = None
    # Do something else with the cloned object
    new_objects.append(obj)
serializer = MySerializer(data=new_objects, many=True) # YIELDS ERROR
if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
    serializer.save()
return Response(serializer.data)
```

What if you don't want to have to set the id of the object to None? The `.values` method allows you to specify the fields of the model you want

so a modified version of your code that is more straightforward will be

```
objects_to_clone = MyModel.objects.filter(...).values('name', 'description') # fake info of course
serializer = MySerializer(data=objects_to_clone, many=True) # YIELDS ERROR
if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
    serializer.save()
return Response(serializer.data)
```